# Como adiciono uma primary no hive versão 0.14.0.2.2.0.0-2041?

Tags: hadoop, hive

Como adiciono uma primary no hive versão  0.14.0.2.2.0.0-2041   ?

Tentativa

```
CREATE TABLE simple_rule (
  simple_rule_id           int(10) unsigned default '0' not null auto_increment,
  condition_analysis_id    int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  goal_analysis_id         int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (simple_rule_id),
  UNIQUE (condition_analysis_id, goal_analysis_id)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

O Hive não é um banco relacional e não existe o mesmo conceito de chave-primaria/estrangeira.

Mas você pode adicionar essa informação no Metadado da tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE simple_rule (
    simple_rule_id          int 
    condition_analysis_id   int,
    goal_analysis_id        int,
)
TBLPROPERTIES("PRIMARY KEY"="simple_rule_id");
```

Mas reforço que isso não fará nenhuma diferença na tabela.

Comment: Obrigado , como eu consigo um campo com registros unicos , em caso de repetir a mesma carga ?

Comment: O Hive está em constante evolução, [conforme a versão pode existir PRIMARY KEY](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-Constraints). A linguagem "SQL do Hive" (por vezes abreviada HQL) é uma abstração (não importa o fato de estar implementando depois MapReduce), e como tal, **é orientada ao modelo relacional**, e tanto quanto possível compatível com os (antigos) padrões ISO da linguagem SQL.